# How to deploy container images from private repositories ( Openshift )

Tags: openshift

Currently, I am doing a deployment to OpenShift cluster through Jenkins pipeline. But it went not successful. Refer to the screenshot.[Deploy script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7q4L.png)

[image: Build script]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What was the error message? What is not working as expected?

Comment: No error message its just that it doesn't build and deploy image to Openshift cluster with that script. I have attached the jenkinsfile implementation script pipeline which i call the build.sh and deploy.sh script.